# reuse pngPtr and infoPtr in libpng

Tags: png, libpng

I am using libpng in a project I am working on. Right now, frames are read 1 by 1 into the memory, using the following commands to allocate memory to the `read` and `info` structs:

```
pngPtr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
infoPtr = png_create_info_struct(pngPtr);
```

Currently, after an image is loaded, the above pointers are destroyed using:

```
png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, (png_infopp)0, (png_infopp)0);
```

However, I'd like to be able to generate the pointers before the process of reading the png files to the memory starts (only once), and destroy them once after all the PNG files are read. In other words, I'd like to be able to create the pointers once, and reuse them.

The issue I get with the new method is that if I don't destroy the pointers after the first PNG file is read, the call to

```
png_read_info(pngPtr, infoPtr);
```

fails, when libPng attempts to load the second PNG file. Is there any particular property of the pointers that needs to be reset for them to be reusable for the subsequent PNG files?

For the sake of brevity, I avoided putting too much code, but I can provide more if needed.

Comment: Are there any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible (or supported) to reuse the structs. No mention of it in the public documentation, and peeking inside the [current sources](http://libpng.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libpng/libpng;a=blob_plain;f=png.c;hb=HEAD) shows some old `png_info_init` that has been deprecated/disable in new versions. I guess you might do some hacking (with or without modifying the libpng source) to accomplish your goal, but I wouldn't recommend that - it seems more trouble than benefit. If you really insist, I'd got to the [libpng mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=png-mng-implement) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

When libpng is patched to support APNG files, it reuses the structs.  The reset code is near the end of pngrutil.c.  Beware that this makes direct access to members of the png_struct, which is not visible to applications since libpng-1.4.0.

I'm not sure it would be worth while, though.  The png struct itself isn't very big.  The memory is consumed mostly by the pixel data (pointed to by row_pointers) which is already under your control and can be reused to your heart's content before you destroy it.

Search the web for "apng patch" to find one.  There are two at http://sourceforge.net, one in the "apng" project and the other in the "libpng-apng" project.